# How to show automatically notification when two textbox have same time or a messagebox in windows form C#?

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to show notification when two textbox have same time to give notification or messagebox.

for example:
i have two textbox. one textbox1 show system short time only like (1:05 PM) and enter the textbox1 so second textbox2 show (1:06 PM) then after 1 minute textbox1 and textbox2 have same time like (1:06 PM) then windows form show notification or message box that's it.

// under this method textbox1 show current and compare with textbox2
    if same time show message box but unfortunately not working as like :(

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
            textBox1.Text = current.ToShortTimeString();

            if (textBox2.Text == textBox1.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Okay");
            }
        }

//// this code to start timer in textbox1

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            timer1.Start();
        }
/// this code working on add next 1 minute in textbox2
```

(for example: textbox1 is 1:05 PM and hit enter key textbox2 show 1:06 PM)

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
     {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        textBox2.Text = dt.AddMinutes(1).ToShortTimeString();
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! You only compare both textboxes at the very beginning in Form2_Load. So, the change of the second checkbox is not recognized anymore. You will need to check the values of both boxes on regular basis, or if one of them changes (OnTextChanged). Did you try debugging?

Comment: Yes but two textbox have same time and no automatically show notification or message box